# 2 simple .htaccess url-rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to set 2 rules:

1. if I type http://www.mydomain.it/notizie/LeDelizieDiCasa, htaccess has to load http://www.mydomain.it/?rssfeed=LeDelizieDiCasa page
2. www.mydomain.it/categoria/Cucina htaccess has to load http://www.mydomain.it/?categoryfeed=Cucina

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?rssfeed=Cucina
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.it/categoria/Cucina [R,L]
```

but it doesn't work, and if I go to http://www.mydomain.it/categoria/Cucina I have error 404 returned.

Who can help me?

mycurrent .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#rule 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^notizie/([^/]+)$ /?rssfeed=$1 [L]

#rule 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^categoria/([^/]+)$ /?categoryfeed=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help you, because I don't see your question or your problem...
I don't know why you add the `www.` or not.

1) Redirect `notizie/LeDelizieDiCasa` to `http://www.mydomain.it/?rssfeed=LeDelizieDiCasa` with:

```
RewriteRule notizie/LeDelizieDiCasa/? http://www.mydomain.it/?rssfeed=LeDelizieDiCasa [NC,L]
```

2) Redirect `/categoria/Cucina` to `http://mydomain.it/?categoryfeed=Cucina`:

```
RewriteRule categoria/Cucina/? http://www.mydomain.it/?rssfeed=LeDelizieDiCasa [NC,L]
```

Add that before `#rule 1`.

Ask, if it's not that...